# Cannot use ArrayField from Djongo Models

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

I'm trying to make an app with Django using MongoDB as my database engine, so I'm using [Djongo](https://www.djongomapper.com/) as ORM.
In my models, I have defined a Client class, which is intended to contain an array of Profiles (authorized people to login in name of client).

In the [Djongo Documentation](https://www.djongomapper.com/using-django-with-mongodb-array-field/), it says one can use the ArrayField class in models in order to store an array to the database. The point is that I followed the example in the documentation (even I tried to copy without changing anything) and it isn't working. When running the view, I always get this error:

"Value: Profile object (None) must be an instance of <class 'list'>"

I have the following models.py:

```
from django import forms
from djongo import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    _id=models.ObjectIdField()

    fname = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    class Meta:
        abstract=True

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields =(
            'fname', 'lname', 'email', 'password',
        )

class Client(models.Model): #informacion del cliente
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    authorized = models.ArrayField(
        model_container=Profile,
        model_form_class=ProfileForm
    )

    objects = models.DjongoManager()

class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = (
            'name', 'authorized'
        )
```

I have a form that uses ClientForm, and the view renders properly. However, when submitting the form I get the error I said at the beginning. I'm searched the whole internet and didn't get any idea of what is causing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have bumped into a similar error a couple of days ago, I was trying to store an object (in your case it's Profile) directly to the ArrayField, I was trying to do something like:

```
client = Client.object.first()
client.authorized = {

    'fname': form.validated_data['first name'],
    'last': form.validated_data['last name'],
    'email': form.validated_data['email'],
    'password': form.validated_data['Password'],
}
client.save()
```

the right way to do it is:

```
client = Client.object.first()
    client.authorized = [{
    
        'fname': form.validated_data['first name'],
        'last': form.validated_data['last name'],
        'email': form.validated_data['email'],
        'password': form.validated_data['Password'],
    }]
    client.save()
```

you'll need to store it as a `list` object by wrapping it around `[]`

that's how I was able to solve it in my case, I think yours is similar, try the above solution, and if it doesn't work, maybe you should share more details like your `views.py`

Comment: I tried by doing that before I answered this question but didn't work... Anyway, I've changed my model so I don't need an array anymore and the app is already working. Thanks for your help and sharing your experience!

Comment: Finally I had to return to the original model, so I had to face this problem again... and your solution definitively works :-)

Comment: I'm glad I could help :-). 
I just want to add something, if you want to update the stored list, you'll need to retrieve it, append an element to it (just like you would do with a normal list), and then save it